# Microsoft Platform Ready Test Tool - Select Primary Executable when they are on a different server

Tags: sql-server, msdn

I am using the Microsoft Platform Ready Test Tool 4.1 and am trying to run through the SQL Server 2012 Data Platform Test

My SQL Server 2012 is running on a Windows 2012 server, and all the prerequisite tests are passing.

But then I come to step 1: Select Primary Executable(s) of Your Application, and get the following error Message:

```
You must identify your application's primary executable(s) in the below list. 
If no executable is displayed below, you must browse and add your applications's primary 
executable that makes the connection to SQL Server. If your application is IIS/PHP/COM+ 
based solution, then you must add the corresponding framework executable(s) that makes the connection to SQL Server.
```

So, my Application is a .Net 4.5 web Application that is running on a different VM from the SQL Server.

So my question is then: How can i add the files needed? And which files am I supposed to add anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I must have either overlooked some documentation, or that it isnt clear enough.

Answer from mprsupport@microsoft.com:

"Web applications need to take the Windows Server 2012R2 test – this is the only test which allows this type of configuration for competency."